# What is the opposite of SQL Use DatabaseName to NOT USE database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

When I am working on my database I connect with USE  but what if I want to stop using the database, what is the opposite of USE?

I am using MS SQL Server Mgmt Studio in a Query window to call the USE.

Comment: Do you want to use another database?

Comment: Per [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188366.aspx): "Changes the database context to the specified database" - so what is the opposite of *changing* the database context?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Changing it back? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your only option is to use another database, or end the script - there is no End Use as it were.

Comment: I figured this might be the case. Appreciate it.

Comment: Use tempdb      will get you "off" a database if you need to.